# How to get window.event in removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This script is getting `#testDiv` and add some listeners to it and works fine:

```
(function() {
    this.testObject = function() {
        /*options*/
        this.options = arguments[0];
    };

    /*make object*/
    testObject.prototype.make = function(){

        this.targetElement = document.getElementById('testDiv');

        this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt){
            ...
        });
        this.targetElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(evt){
            ...
        });
        this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
            ...
        });

    };
}());
```

But as far as I know, in order to remove the listeners I should use real functions instead of anonymous functions in `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`:

```
this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownFunction(evt));
this.targetElement.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpFunction(evt));
this.targetElement.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveFunction(evt));
```

And in `removeEventListener`:

```
this.targetElement.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownFunction(evt));
this.targetElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpFunction(evt));
this.targetElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveFunction(evt));
```

There is a problem here, I can't get `evt` ( event ) handler in real functions:

> Error: evt is undefined

For example in `mouseDownFunction` I get undefined :

```
function mouseDownFunction(evt){

    console.log( evt ); // evt is undefined
    console.log( window.event ) // undefined

}
```

How can I get `evt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
var listener = function (event) {
  /* do something here */
};
this.targetElement.addEventListener('click', listener, false);
this.targetElement.removeEventListener('click', listener, false);
```

Or just this, which should work exactly the same:

```
function myListener(event) {
/* do something here */
}

this.targetElement.addEventListener('click', myListener, false);
```

And remove it:

```
this.targetElement.removeEventListener('click', myListener, false);
```

Note that when you add the event and pass in the function, you don't need to add the argument.  You are just adding a reference to the function (function pointer).

Comment: what if I have extra 'arguments` ?

Comment: Do you really need extra arguments?  Can you show me your use case?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Haukur answer. You can also do it like this.

```
this.targetElement.addEventListener('click', function(event){myClickFunction(event);});
this.targetElement.removeEventListener('click', function(event){myClickFunction(event);});
```

In this we are creating a anonymous function as you were doing earlier and then pass the parameter of that anonymous function to your function ie `myClickFunction`.

In case of extra parameters, just add them in the function.

```
 this.targetElement.addEventListener('click', function(event){myClickFunction(event, param1, param2, param3);});

 myClickFucntion(event, param1, param2, param3){
 }
```